# Destructing a javascript object to get inner object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using the following code to get object from react state.

```
const { organizations } = this.state;
```

The sate object is as following.

```
this.state = {
    userOrganizations: {},
    OrganizationUsers: {}
}
```

`userOrganizations` is actually an object with an inner object named `organizations`. How can I map this using es6 code?

**Edit**

What I actually need is to get inner objects of both the `userOrganizations` and `OrganizationUsers` using the following code.

```
const { organizations, users } = this.state;
```

The `organizations` and `users` are sub objects which are inside the `userOrganizations` and `OrganizationUsers`.

So when I want to handle them, will they work with just calling

```
const { organizations, users } = this.state.userOrganizations, this.state.OrganizationUsers;
```

Comment: Something like `const { organizations } = this.state.userOrganizations` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest destructruring like

```
const { userOrganizations : { organizations } } = this.state;
```

or simply write

```
const {  organizations  } = this.state.userOrganizations;
```

Comment: Well this answered my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use dot notation until you get to the parent object just above the property you want

```js
const obj = { outer: { inner: 'value' }};
const { inner } = obj.outer;
console.log(inner);
```

To destructure more than one thing at a time in different nested levels, try something like:

```js
const x = {
  state: {
    userOrganizations: {
      organizations: 'orgValue'
    },
    OrganizationUsers: {
      users: 'userValue'
    }
  }
}
const { userOrganizations: { organizations }, OrganizationUsers: { users } } = x.state;
console.log(organizations + ' ' + users);
```

Comment: what if the code looked like this `const { organizations, fooBar } = this.state;` which is another inner object. Then what is the best approach?

Comment: What do you mean, what does the inner object look like, and what are you trying to extract out of it? Are you wondering how to destructure from multiple levels at once?

Comment: Added another snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple but still many got it wrong. Here is an example of inner destructuring

```
const obj = {
    someArray: [ 1, 2, 3],
    someInnerObj : {num: 123, txt: 'text'}
}

const {someArray: [first,second], someInnerObj: { num: myNum, txt: meText}} = obj
console.log(first,second,myNum,meText)
```

Try it in console

Answer (score 0):

If i'am not wrong this should solve your issue,

```
const { organizations } = this.state.userOrganizations;
```